# String parsing C# creating segments?

Tags: c#

I have a string in the form of:

```
"company=ABCorp, location=New York, revenue=10million, type=informationTechnology"
```

I want to be able to parse this string out and get "name", "value" pairs in the form of

company = ABCCorp

location= New York etc.

This could be any suitable data structure to store. I was thinking maybe a `Dictionary<string, string>()` but im open to suggestions.

Is there a suitable way of doing this in C#?

EDIT: My final goal here is to have something like this:

Array[company] = ABCCorp.
Array[location] = New York.

What data structure could we use to achieve the above? MY first thought is a Dictionary but I am not sure if Im missing anything.

thanks

Comment: You can pull those values with regular expressions.

Comment: One way would be to split on the `,`, and then loop through the resulting array and split on the `=`. There may be fancier ways as well.

Comment: is there always going to be a space after the comma?

Comment: This looks like CSV. Have you thought of using a CSV parser and [stop rolling your own](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)?

Comment: Could use Xdocument and parse via attributes.

Comment: @retslig, XDocument??? Where did you see XML in the example shown?

Comment: Of course you would have to add a begin tag and end tag... not complicated.

Comment: And what about the attributes? He wants to split with the commas. I don't see how XML would help with this task.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  - the OP said he was open to suggestions.

Comment: @Brian, so you are suggesting to replace the string he has with XML? That would of course work if he can modify his input string. You could post it as answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - No I'm not suggesting that, someone else did.  you were questioning why someone made a comment about xml and I was pointing out that the OP said he was open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx), you could do:

```
var original = "company=ABCorp, location=New York, revenue=10million, type=informationTechnology";

var split = original.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim().Split('='));

Dictionary<string,string> results = split.ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "company=ABCorp, location=New York, revenue=10million, type=informationTechnology";
var pairs = s.Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Split('='))
        .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

pairs is Dictionary with the key value pair.  The only caveat is you will probably want to deal with any white space between the comma and the string.

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on the expected syntax. One way to do this is to use String.Split:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

First split on comma, then iterate over all items in the string list returned and split those on equality.

However, this requires that comma and equality are never present in the values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming a weak RegEx/LINQ background so here's a way to do it without anything "special".

```
string text = "company=ABCorp, location=New York, revenue=10million, type=informationTechnology";

string[] pairs = text.Split(',');
Dictionary<string, string> dictData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string currPair in pairs)
{
    string[] data = currPair.Trim().Split('=');

    dictData.Add(data[0], data[1]);
}
```

This has the requirement that a comma (`,`) and an equal-sign (`=`) never exist in the data other than as delimiters.

This relies heavily on [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Assuming the commas are always present, I would favor this approach over Regex I think.  We can't really answer whether the string format could come in with other delimiters, or what needs to be guarded against though.